# Why JSON_ENCODE does not return "/" (Slash) it always return like this"\/"?

Tags: php, mysql, json

When i insert url like this

```
alliedpaint-001-site1.smarterasp.net/white.png
```

in mysql and encode it using json my url shows like this

```
alliedpaint-001-site1.smarterasp.net\/white.png
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_encode returns the string, it inserts "\" in order to avoid special interpretation.

you can do 2 things-

1) json_encode($mystring, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

or

replace "\" with space using regex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh i see Thanks a lot :D